# Stop Build/Run From Netbeans IDE and still run a shutdownhook

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I make my program do something when I click end build / stop running from the NetBeans IDE? I have just found out about shutdownhooks, but it doesnt run if I stop running the program, from the IDE, in the middle of doing something.

Comment: You don't. Mainly because there is no way to reliably call a shutdown hook on a terminate (which is what the "stop" button does).